# How to solve this error: ValueError: Shapes (None, 1) and (None, 2) are incompatible

Tags: deep-learning, resnet

I have tried these two loss='binary_crossentropy' activation='sigmoid' as well but nothing is working for me. How can I solve this error?

```
        batch_size = 2
    
        datagen_train = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
        datagen_test = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
    
        generator_train = datagen_train.flow_from_directory(directory=train_dir,
                                                       batch_size=batch_size,
                                                        target_size=(256,256),
                                                       shuffle = True,
                                                       class_mode = 'binary',
                                                       color_mode = 'grayscale')
    
        generator_test = datagen_test.flow_from_directory(directory=test_dir,
                                                        batch_size=batch_size,
                                                        target_size=(256,256),
                                                        color_mode = 'grayscale',
                                                        class_mode = 'binary',
                                                        shuffle = False)
    
        steps_test = generator_test.n // batch_size
        print(steps_test)
    
        epochs = 10
        steps_per_epoch = generator_train.n // batch_size
        print(steps_per_epoch)
    
        model = ResNet50(include_top=True)
    
        model.summary()
    
        model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',optimizer='adam',metrics=['accuracy'])
    
        hist = model.fit(generator_train,
                               epochs=epochs,
                               steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch,
                               validation_data = generator_test,
                               validation_steps = steps_test)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've used a sample binary class dataset(cats and dogs dataset) to reproduce the issue.

The issue was with this line: `model = ResNet50(include_top=True)` where you did not build the model properly.

Replacing this:

```
 model = ResNet50(include_top=True)
```

with the follwing code solves the error:

```
model = ResNet50(input_shape=(256, 256,3), include_top=False, weights="imagenet")
model = Sequential()
model.add(ResNet50(include_top=False, weights='imagenet', pooling='max'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
```

Let us know if the issue still persists. Thanks!